# Unecessary spacing in inline table

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

Putting 5 columns in a row for an html email blast. I have margin and cell spacing at 0, but I'm getting huge amounts of spacing between the 5 images, so I can't figure out what I'm missing. I've been able to do this with 2 columns in a row, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong now. Any help appreciated

https://jsfiddle.net/baboles/mpbd7b91/

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5">
             <a href="#">
             <img src ="#" style= "display: block; width: 600px;">
             </a>
        </td>
    </tr>

<!--Column 1-->

 <tr>
     <td align="right" colspan="1" width="120">
         <a style = "margin: 0px;" href="#">
         <img src="#" style="display: block; width: 120px;">
         </a>
      </td>

<!-- Column 2 -->

         <td align="right" colspan="1" width="120">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="#" width="120px" style="display: block; width: 120px;">
         </a>
      </td>


<!-- Column 3 -->

         <td align="center" colspan="1" width="120">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="#" width="120px" style="display: block; width: 120px;">
         </a>
      </td>


<!-- Column 4 -->

         <td align="left" colspan="1" width="120">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="#" width="120px" style="display: block; width: 120px;">
         </a>
      </td>

<!-- Column 5 -->

         <td align="left" colspan="1" width="120">
         <a href="#">
         <img src="#" width="120px" style="display: block; width: 120px;">
         </a>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a https://jsfiddle.net/ or so..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/baboles/mpbd7b91/

Comment: ok...which spacing are you talking about?

Comment: The spacing between the 5 smaller images. I'm trying to get them all lined up against each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the following steps:

1) remove width="100%" in the table tag

2) set the css table-layout of the table to fixed. Like below

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: fixed;margin: 0px auto;">
```

Comment: Getting closer, that worked on the jsfiddle.net, but not in constant contact. Also, on jsfiddle.net and constant contact the body is no longer centered

Comment: Try this. Add margin: 0px auto; will make the table center.

Comment: You've been great man, really appreciate it, still getting gaps in constant contact though https://www.flickr.com/photos/43079452@N03/24331340174/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: I copied just how you hadd it in jsfiddle and put it in constant contact. works like a charm. Youre the man!

Comment: Try to set the table to the 600px width of the top image. That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that there is only space between your images when the table has a lot of horizontal width to fill.  You need to fix the width of your table so that it doesn't grow bigger than it needs to.

Alternatively, you could ditch the 5 column table layout and display the images inline-block or float them.  When using inline-block, make sure the markup does not have spaces between elements, this can be achieved with comments like so:

```
   <img ...><!--
--><img ...><!--
--><img ...>
```